# How to toggle sidebar in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-sidebar

I want to toggle a sidebar on toolbar icon click. I define my toolbar in  ff-sidebar.js file:

```
var mainWindow = null;

function startup() {
  mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                     .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                     .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                     .rootTreeItem
                     .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                     .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

  // Sidebar is loaded and mainwindow is ready                   
}

function shutdown() {
  // Sidebar is unloading
}

window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", shutdown, false);
```

Any idea how to do this? I can't find any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

In my `ff-overlay.xul` my sidebar is defined like this:

```
<broadcasterset id="mainBroadcasterSet">
    <broadcaster id="viewSidebar_smsflatrate"
                 label="&smsflatrateSidebar.label;"
                 autoCheck="false"
                 type="checkbox"
                 group="sidebar"
                 sidebarurl="chrome://smsflatrate/content/ff-sidebar.xul"
                 sidebartitle="&smsflatrateSidebar.label;"
                 oncommand="toggleSidebar('viewSidebar_smsflatrate');" />
  </broadcasterset>
```

To toggle the sidebar just use the following command:

```
toggleSidebar("viewSidebar_smsflatrate");
```